# The solution of $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0, \ t<2x,x>0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the PDE
$$u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0， \ t<2x,x>0$$
$$u|_{t=2x}=\sin x, x>0$$
$$u|_{t=0}=0, u_t|_{t=0}=1 $$
How to find a solution of it

Comment: This is the one dimensional [wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) and it is a standard exercise to solve this equation.  What part of the solution procedure is stopping you?

Comment: The boundary condition is hard to deal with

Answer (score 1):

The general solution to $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0$ is $u=F(x+t)+G(x-t)$.

The three boundary conditions result in the system

$$ \begin{cases} F(x)+G(x) & = 0 \\ F'(x)-G'(x) &=1 \\ F(3x)+G(-x) & =\sin x \end{cases} \qquad (x>0) $$

For $x>0$, then, the first gives $G(x)=-F(x)$, substituted into the second gives $F'(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ and so we may say that $F(x)=F_0+\frac{1}{2}x$ for $x>0$. However, $x-t$ may be negative so we need to know $G$ at negative values as well, so substituting into the third equation (solving for $G(-x)$, then replacing $x$ with $-x$) gives us:

$$ G(x) = \frac{3}{2}x-\sin x-F_0 \qquad (x<0) $$

You'll have to substitute $F$ and $G$ into $u$ and simplify according to the sign of $x-t$.

Comment: @Isham When you take the derivative of $u(x,t)=F(x+t)+G(x-t)$ with respect to $t$ and plug in $t=0$ you get $\left. u_t\right|_{t=0}=F'(x)-G'(x)$ which we're told is $1$.